# Bayes estimator from a geometric distribution with a uniform prior

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

X is a random variable with Ber(p), 0

Y is the number of trials until a success occurs.

Assume the prior p is unif(0,1).

I have trouble in figuring out the posterior density f(p|Y).

With the knowledge of f(p|Y)=$\frac{f(Y|p)f(p)}{f(Y)}=\frac{p^{n}(1-p)^{\sum x_{i}-n}\cdot 1_{(0<p<1)}}{\int_{0}^{1}p^{n}(1-p)^{\sum x_{i}-n}dp}$.

I have two concerns about the equation above.

First, I'm not sure whether the joint pdf f(Y|p) calculated by $\prod_{i=1}^{n}p(1-p)^{x_{i}-1}$ is correct because the support of Y is not cleared based on the given information; second, the integration in the denominator is kind of weird.

Could anyone share your though with me regarding this question? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a geometric distribution with a beta prior (conjugate)

$X_i \sim geometric(\theta)$

where

$Pr(X_i=j|\theta)=(1-\theta)^{j-1}\theta$

so the likelihood is

$L(\theta;x)=\prod_{i=1}^n \theta (1-\theta)^{x_i-1}$

$L(\theta;x)= \theta^n (1-\theta)^{S-n}$

where $S=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$

using the conjugate beta prior which has a pdf proportional to

$\theta^{a-1} (1-\theta)^{b-1}$

the posterior becomes

$\theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1} \theta^n (1-\theta)^{S-n}=\theta^{a+n-1} (1-\theta)^{b+S-n-1}$

which is simply a beta distribution

Now is we use a $Beta(1,1)$ as the prior which is the same as $Uniform(0,1)$ you get the posterior you want.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm wondering why we need Binomial here not Geometric distribution for Y. thanks!

Comment: my apologies, i did not read the question quite as well as i should have. But the idea should not change much. The conjugate prior to the geometric distribution is a beta distribution. So if you switch the likelihoods you can calculate another beta posterior

Comment: i have tried to update the answer. Sorry if it is a bit messy