# Geometric Prior Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian

What is an appropriate posterior distribution given a geometric prior distribution? I think a Bernoulli posterior would be appropriate, but am unsure if this is correct. Can anyone verify my idea, or give an alternative posterior?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not choose the *posterior* distribution. A statistical model is (in simple words) a mathematical object which takes as input :

- observations $\mathbf{y} \in \mathcal{Y}$,
- parameters $\boldsymbol\theta \in \Theta$.

In a Bayesian framework, you consider the parameters $\boldsymbol\theta$ as random variable. The probability distribution $p$ of $\boldsymbol\theta$ is called *prior distribution* ($\boldsymbol\theta \sim p(\boldsymbol\theta)$) and is choosen by the statistician. The prior somehow inputs into the model your knowledge about the parameters, how certain you are that the "true" parameters are in a specific region of the parameters space.

Given a statistical model and a prior distribution, you can define the *posterior distribution* of your parameters given the observations. This probability distribution is $p(\boldsymbol\theta \mid \mathbf{y})$, the conditional distribution of $\boldsymbol\theta$ given the observations $\mathbf{y}$. Using the Bayes rule, you have :
$$ p(\boldsymbol\theta \mid \mathbf{y}) \propto p(\mathbf{y} \mid \boldsymbol\theta)p(\boldsymbol\theta) \tag{$\star$}$$
where $p(\mathbf{y} \mid \boldsymbol\theta)$ is the *likelihood* of your observations $\mathbf{y}$. The likelihood function $\boldsymbol\theta \in \Theta \mapsto p(\mathbf{y} \mid \boldsymbol\theta)$ is given by your statistical model. From $(\star$), you see that the posterior distribution is not something you choose. It is the result of "statistical model + prior".

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So I would do posterior = (geometric pdf)*(geometric MLE)? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I forgot to direct my comment to you

Comment: @spidergirl : Yes, but I'm not completely sure what you mean by "Geometric MLE". What is your statistical model exactly ?

Comment: I have the following: g(x;theta)=1/10(9/10)^(x-1) and the MLE of a geometric distribution is: theta-hat=1/x, so I would get a posterior of 1/10(9/10)(x-1)*1/x, right?

Comment: @spidergirl : If you're talking about MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimates), you're not in a Bayesian framework. In addition to this, your model is : $P(X \mid \theta) = \theta(1-\theta)^{X-1}$. Then, what prior do you assume on $\theta$ ? Since $\theta \in [0,1]$, you could use a Uniform prior or a Beta prior... Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097547/bayes-estimator-from-a-geometric-distribution-with-a-uniform-prior

Comment: I am attempting a Bayesian framework, I am just confused on how to set it up. I want a geometric prior, so I guess I'm not sure what my likelihood is then? I know I'm supposed to multiply the pdf by some likelihood to get the posterior.

Comment: @spidergirl : You cannot consider a Geometric prior on the parameter $\theta$ since $\theta$ is supposed to be in $[0,1]$.